# How to iterate through 2d array in constraint in minizinc correctly?

Tags: arrays, constraint-programming, minizinc

I want to solve the problem of coloring the graph. It is the problem when a graph should be colored in a minimum number of colors subject to no adjacent vertices is colored in the same color.
Here is my code with a toy graph.

```
int: N_Vertices=4;
int: N_Edges=3;
array[1..N_Edges, 1..2] of int: Adjacency;
Adjacency = [| 0, 1
             | 1, 2
             | 1, 3|];
array [1..N_Vertices] of var int: coloring;

constraint forall(e in 1..N_Edges)(coloring[Adjacency[e, 1]] != coloring[Adjacency[e, 2]]);
constraint forall(c in coloring)(c >= 0);

solve minimize (max(coloring));
```

But it gives

```
 WARNING: undefined result becomes false in Boolean context
  (array access out of bounds)
Playground:11:
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with e = 1
  in binary '!=' operator expression
  in array access

  WARNING: model inconsistency detected
Playground:11:
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with e = 1
  in binary '!=' operator expression
  in array access
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====
```

I suppose I do something wrong with `Adjacency` iteration in the first constraint. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `Adjacency`: The values are in base 0 but `coloring` has base 1 (`array[1..N_Vertices]`). MiniZinc has base 1 indexing as default.

The simplest is to change the indices in `Adjacency` to base 1 instead:

```
Adjacency = [| 1, 2
             | 2, 3
             | 2, 4|];
```

Then the solution would be:

```
coloring = array1d(1..4, [1, 0, 1, 1]);
----------
==========
```

If you want to keep the base 0 indices in `Adjacency`, then you have to do some other adjustments by replacing `1..N_Edges` with `0..N_Edges-1`:

```
int: N_Vertices=4;
int: N_Edges=3;
array[0..N_Edges-1, 1..2] of int: Adjacency;        

Adjacency = array2d(0..N_Edges-1,1..2,[| 0, 1
             | 1, 2
             | 1, 3|]);

array[0..N_Vertices-1] of var int: coloring;
constraint forall(e in 0..N_Edges-1)(coloring[Adjacency[e, 1]] != coloring[Adjacency[e, 2]]);
constraint forall(c in coloring)(c >= 0);
```

The answer:

```
coloring = array1d(1..4, [1, 0, 1, 1]);
```

Also, I recommend that you give `coloring` a proper domain instead of `var int`, e.g.:

```
array[0..N_Vertices-1] of 0..4: coloring; % recommended
% ....
% Then this is not needed:
% constraint forall(c in coloring)(c >= 0);
```

Comment: Why _does_ MiniZinc have base 0 indexing as default? Is it because it is often practical to give 0 with special semantics for example "no such value" or "missing segment"? It would make sense, as there is no NULL. Even global constraints use 0 in this way, being named "foo_except_0".

Comment: @DavidTonhofer MiniZinc has  base `1` indexing as default (but I guess you mean that). You might have a point regarding `foo_except_0`, but this has more about the values in the arrays, not the indexing. I rather think that base 1 indexing as default is from historical reasons from other systems (e.g. Comet, OPL, AMPL?, Prolog's nth/3?) that tends to use indexing base 1. (Personally I think it's more natural to work in base 1 indexing when modeling problems, but that's another matter.)

Comment: Thanks, that works! Seems that you have the experience with that, could you please answer couple more questions? How can I specify the order of `int_search`? For example, go in order of degree node decrease in graph coloring problem?

Comment: @hakank Thank you. Yes, I meant 1 of course. I have to say I'm so used to base-0 indexing (base-1 indexing is actually _naming_ while base-0 indexing is actually _offsetting_) that I'm having trouble with the 1-based convention. Plus the mod/div calculations for multi-dimensional array access don't look nice. (I remember that FORTRAN started it all ... and now Julia has it too!)

Comment: @Nourless This is a long story. This might help: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/mzn_search.html?highlight=annotation

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Julia and 1 based indexing: Yes, and that is a plus for Julia in my book. :-)

Comment: @Nourless Please ask this (about `int_search`) in a new question instead, if @DavidTonhofer's hint is not enough.

Comment: @hakank, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432458/is-there-a-way-to-customize-int-search-in-minizinc